# Turning off Bluetooth also turns off Wi-Fi on HP Pavilion dm4-1150ea

Tags: 12.04, wireless, bluetooth, hp

Just upgraded from 10.04 to 12.04 on a dual boot HP Pavilion dm4-1150ea. If I disable Bluetooth then Wi-Fi is also disabled.  I have looked at these similar reported issues:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/962621
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1947495&page=2

I have also logged in using classic GNOME, but this didn't work.

Any suggestions about a fix for this?  Note that all was working on 10.04.

******Update*******

A bit more info:

```
eamon@eamon-laptop:/media$ sudo rfkill list
[sudo] password for eamon: 
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
13: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Try to turn off bluetooth in software......

```
eamon@eamon-laptop:/media$ sudo rfkill block 1
eamon@eamon-laptop:/media$ sudo rfkill list
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    **Soft blocked: yes**
    Hard blocked: no
1: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    **Soft blocked: yes**
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Both the bluetooth and wifi are turned off.

Try to unblock wifi...

```
eamon@eamon-laptop:/media$ sudo rfkill unblock 0
eamon@eamon-laptop:/media$ sudo rfkill list
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    **Soft blocked: yes**
    Hard blocked: no
1: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

That didn't work.

Turn off wifi using the hardware switch...

```
eamon@eamon-laptop:/media$ sudo rfkill list
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    **Hard blocked: yes**
1: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    **Hard blocked: yes**
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Turn on wifi using the hardware switch...

```
eamon@eamon-laptop:/media$ sudo rfkill list
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem here on a Siemens laptop and I researched this about 9 months ago under 12.04, so I don't remember all the details, but the conclusion was that the Siemens uses the same DSP chip for both the Bluetooth and the WiFi and the key combination to turn on Bluetooth and WiFi (in my case: <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) blocks the chip, not the functionality inside the chip, so there is only one thing to do: live with it and blame it on the beancounters to use only one chip instead of two...  :(